# FrameRate issue with vlcj

Tags: java, vlcj

i recently tried to record my screen using a modified version of one of the sample codes i found here in stackoverflow but as you can see yourself , the saved file's framerate is extremely awful. can you please help?
here's the code i used:

```
public class CaptureTest {

private final MediaPlayerFactory factory;
private final HeadlessMediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    boolean found = new NativeDiscovery().discover();
    System.out.println(found);
    System.out.println(LibVlc.INSTANCE.libvlc_get_version());
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new CaptureTest().start("screen://");
        }
    });
}

public CaptureTest() {
    factory = new MediaPlayerFactory();

    mediaPlayer = (HeadlessMediaPlayer) factory.newHeadlessMediaPlayer();
}

private void start(String mrl) {

    File dir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Videos");
    dir.mkdirs();


    String fileName =  "C:\\Users\\Reza Taheri\\Documents\\video7.mp4";

    String[] options = {
            ":sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,venc=x264{cfr=16},acodec=mp4a,vfilter=canvas{width=854,height=480},samplerate=4096}:std{mux=mp4,access=file,dst=" + fileName + "}", ":input-slave=screen://",":screen-fps=24"
    };



    JPanel cp = new JPanel();
    JButton recordButton = new JButton("Record");
    cp.add(recordButton);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("vlcj");
    frame.setContentPane(cp);
    frame.setLocation(10, 10);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
    });
    recordButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            frame.setState(JFrame.ICONIFIED);
            mediaPlayer.playMedia(mrl, options);
        }
    });
    frame.setVisible(true);


}
```

}

i'm using windows 10 with latest version of vlcj and vlc media player.

Answer (score 0):

I'll admit I didn't know this was possible(to record screen with vlcj) but I'm going to say that the problem is not vlcj related since you pass lots of parameters into libvlc and it's those parameters that tell libvlc to record your screen (if I have understood the code correctly)

I can't help with those though but read more about libvlc and it's arguments/options.

Answer (score 0):

Your current frame rate is 24 which is good. I think you want to say video quality of saved video is poor. The major factor in video quality is video bitrate. Set bitrate in transcode options and check the video quality again.

e.g. vb=1024 or vb=2000

Also if you want video resolution which matches with your current desktop resolution then you can set scale=1.0 in transcode option

You can find [vlcj java screen recorder example here](http://www.experimentalqa.com/2017/11/record-selenium-test-video-in-mp4.html) which records screen in mp4 format. It uses headless media player so it becomes easy to start screen recording pragmatically in background. I used it to record my selenium tests execution.